# Why aren't we sure that photons and gravitons are massless?

Tags: particle-physics, photons, mass

In particle data group's (PDG) The Review of Particle Physics (2016) page number 29, the mass of the photon is given to be $<1\times10^{-18}eV$ and that of graviton as $<6\times10^{-32}eV$.

- In case those limits are experimental upper bounds, what makes them give theoretical value for gluons and experimental limits for photon and graviton?
- Why aren't we sure that photon's mass is zero, even though we are sure that gluons mass is zero (as given in it)?
- In case they have mass, why do we think graviton may have lesser mass that of the photon even though they both are carriers of forces of similar range?

Comment: I VTC because of duplication (and echos of old texts telling me the neutrino has no mass)

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform In case you mean that those limits are experimental upper bounds, what makes them give theoretical value for gluons and experimental limits for photon and graviton?